# How to disable dropdown after binding dynamically in JqGrid form editing

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

In my JqGrid I am binding the dropdown dynamically, also I want the dropdown to be disabled after bindind, I written the code for this beforeShowForm event in edit portion but it get fired before buildSelect event in colModel,
as a result attribute is not getting applied, please give me some direction to disable the dropdown in this situation.
Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to that question,

```
editOptions{
dataInit: function (elem) {
        $(elem).width(150);
        $(elem).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code , Its may be heplfyll

$("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);
 $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);